# init with delegate protocol

Tags: objective-c, delegates, initialization, protocols

Whenever I create an init that has a delegate conforming to a protocol I write the init as this:

```
- (id)initWithDelegate:(id<ProtocolToConform>)delegate;
```

This way I will have a warning if the creating object does not conform to the protocol.

However I noticed that ie `UIAlertView` init method looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
```

The delegate argument does not specify to conform to the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol? Any clues why Apple has done it that way?

Comment: I thought they were just too lazy to add that, or it might be because all the UIAlertViewDelegate methods are optional, it doesn't matter if the delegate conform to the protocol or not.

Comment: it would not give any benefit in this case, it would be just an extra pain to conforming the protocol to your classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that the API was a big mess a few years ago and they are still fixing all these issues.

Note that until recently many protocols were informal and almost everywhere in the API you could find delegates only as an `id`. Apple is fixing it step by step in every version, for example formal `NSURLConnection` delegates came with iOS 6.0. Or note that in iOS 6.1 some of the `id` return types were changed into `instancetype`.

Well, this was my initial idea, after checking the header files:

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) id /*<UIAlertViewDelegate>*/ delegate
```

It's obvious somebody wanted to add the protocol to the declarations but added only the comment. I am guessing they left it without the protocol for compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

Good question!  I do the same thing in the hope of catching more errors at compile time.

Apple appear to be conforming to their own standards; as stated in [Concepts in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html):

> To implement a delegate for your custom class, complete the following steps:
>
> Declare the delegate accessor methods in your class header file.

```
- (id)delegate;
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate;
```

> Implement the accessor methods. In a memory-managed program, to avoid retain cycles, the setter method should not retain or copy your delegate.

```
- (id)delegate {
    return delegate;
}
 
- (void)setDelegate:(id)newDelegate {
    delegate = newDelegate;
}
```

Comment: Although if you check UITableView.h you can see `@property(nonatomic,assign)   id <UITableViewDelegate>   delegate;` so they seem to mix it up :-)